# What kinds of questions are Technical Support Incidents for?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa

Last year I received two "Technical Support Incidents" in the iPhone developer program, but when I went to renew I found that I would lose them. I have another two for this year, but I'm not really sure about the kind of problems that can be solved by using them.

What kinds of questions are the best use of these Technical Support Incidents? What is the kind of problem I can use them for? What do you receive when you use them? Thanks.

Comment: Those who voted to close: **This *is* a programming question.** “Technical Support Incidents” are provided by Apple's **Developer Technical Support** to registered developers (on the paid plans).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Technical Support Incidents are for when you need code level support for a project you are working on. If your code is hanging up on certain pieces of hardware, or you need help diagnosing a bug in your system, then you can contact the Apple Engineers to help with the particular problem you are having and they will help to resolve the issue.

Notice this is different from a bug in Apple's systems, which is what the bug reporter is for. This is when you need help from Apple to track down a solution to a problem you are having in your code.

I have personally never used it, and with sites like SO, doubt I will unless I hit one of those one in a million edge cases where I code myself into a corner.

More information is on [Apple's website](http://developer.apple.com/support/resources/technical-support.html).

Comment: I have used technical support incidents on more than one occasion. With one problem they were unable to help but confirmed a bug and refunded the incident. With the other they provided what I consider to be a large amount of excellent sample code as well as an answer that fixed my issue.

Comment: @Brendan thanks for the answer. I'm the same, I just come to SO for answers and still have difficulty thinking about what question I would use an incident for.

Comment: @Rob, I love the sound of getting a large amount of sample code. If you don't mind me asking, what was the question you asked them?

Comment: I believe it was an issue with `NSTreeController` and custom views, I don't have the email transcript to hand. It was a couple of years back.

Comment: I have just opened a technical support incident and they replied after 2 days. Hope they will be able to help me.